# Transfer date row to timestamp row concating old date value with time string SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to alter a table in sql by changing a row of the type date to a row of the type timestamp. I want to use the old values of type date and copy them to the new row of type timestamp. Furthermore I want to concat the timestamps with the time "12:00" (noon).

My try:

```
-- Create a temporary TIMESTAMP column
ALTER TABLE guest_group ADD COLUMN create_time_holder TIMESTAMP without time zone NULL;

-- Copy casted value over to the temporary column and set time to 12:00
UPDATE guest_group SET create_time_holder = arrival_date::TIMESTAMP without time zone AS "12:00";
```

The result should be a value (timestamp) containing the old date with the string "12:00"

`2019-12-20 12:00`

Comment: It's not clear whether you want 12 noon or 12 midnight. If you want midnight, then setting the time to 12:00 is incorrect. ISO timestamp standards use the 24 hour clock, meaning 00:00 is midnight.

Comment: I added the information you required to my post @jpmc26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postgres, I think this does what you want:

```
UPDATE guest_group
    SET create_time_holder = arrival_date::date + interval '12 hour';
```